# React Native doctor suggest upgrade Android SDK version but I use lastest version?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

when running react-native doctor

```
Common
✓ Node.js
✓ yarn

Android
✓ ANDROID_HOME
✖ Android SDK - Required for building and installing your app on Android
  - Version found: 23.0.1
  - Version supported: >= 26.x
```

but in build.gradle

```
buildscript {
ext {
    buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
    minSdkVersion = 16
    compileSdkVersion = 28
    targetSdkVersion = 28
    androidXAnnotation = "1.1.0"
    androidXBrowser = "1.0.0"
    androidXCore = "1.0.2"
}
```

I don't know these tools detect setting from and what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an [open issue about this](https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/issues/857).

It seems that `react-native doctor` picks the version at the top when running the command `${ANDROID_HOME}/tools/bin/sdkmanager --list` while it should take the one from the bottom.

You should probably wait for this issue to be resolved!